# How to properly upper bound $\left| \int_{[z_0,z]} |y|^{\alpha} dy \right| $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

Let $z_0 \neq z \in \mathbb C$ be two complex numbers for which $[z_0,z] = \{(z-z_0)t + z_0 : t \in [0,1]\}$ does not cross $0$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \{-1\}$.

I want to upper bound the path-integral
$$\left| \int_{[z_0,z]} |y|^{\alpha} dy \right| = |z-z_0| \int_0^1 |(z-z_0)t + z_0|^{\alpha}dt$$
I would expect something like
$$\left| \int_{[z_0,z]} |y|^{\alpha} dy \right| \leq \frac{||z|^{\alpha + 1} - |z_0|^{\alpha+1}|}{|\alpha + 1|}$$
or at least
$$\left| \int_{[z_0,z]} |y|^{\alpha} dy \right| \leq \frac{|z|^{\alpha + 1} + |z_0|^{\alpha+1}}{|\alpha + 1|}$$
to hold, up to some universal constant. The $(\alpha + 1)^{-1}$ factor (and the $\alpha$ dependence in general) is important. Otherwise, it's quite easy to estimate the integral as done in the [Estimation Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma).

I tried to do something simple as follows
$$\int_0^1 |(z-z_0)t + z_0|^{\alpha}dt \leq \max\{2,2^{\alpha/2}\} \left( \int_0^1 |\Re(z-z_0)t + \Re(z_0) |^{\alpha} dt + \int_0^1 |\Im(z-z_0)t + \Im(z_0) |^{\alpha} dt \right)$$
but splitting the integral like this lead to singularities of type $\Re(z-z_0)^{-1}$, $\Im(z-z_0)^{-1}$ that I cannot get rid of. Moreover, the $2^{\alpha/2}$ factor is not ideal.

If we don't split the integral like I did, we are led to study an integral of the type
$$\int_0^1 (at^2 + bt + c)^{\alpha/2}ds$$
for some real, positive second-order polynomial on $[0,1]$, but I don't know how to study such an integral. However, there might be some easier way to proceed since I'm not looking for an exact value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is symmetrical up to rotations so we can assume that $z, z_0$ have the same real part $x>0$ and write $z= x+ia, z_0= x+ib$. $x$ is actually the norm of the orthogonal projection of $0$ on $(z, z_0)$. The integral then rewrites
$$I =\int_a^b |x+it|^\alpha dt$$
With a change of variables $u=t/x$:
$$I=x^{\alpha+1} \int_{a/x}^{b/x} |1+iu|^\alpha dt$$
Name $J = I / x^{\alpha+1}$ that second integral. When $x \rightarrow \infty$, $J$ behaves like $\frac {b-a} x$ (because $a/x, b/x \rightarrow 0$ and $|1+iu|^\alpha \simeq 1$ for $u \simeq 0$.
So for $x \rightarrow \infty$, $I \simeq (b-a)*x^\alpha$

For $x\rightarrow 0$, $J \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |1+iu|^\alpha < \infty$ if $\alpha <0$ and $J \lesssim \max(|a/x|^\alpha,|b/x|^\alpha) * \frac {b-a} x$ so we get:

- $\alpha <0$: $I \lesssim x^{\alpha+1}$.

-$\alpha \ge 0$: $I \lesssim x^{\alpha} \cdot (b-a)$

For $\alpha \ge 0$ you can actually write from the beginning $I \le \max(|z|^\alpha, |z_0|^\alpha) *(|z-z_0|)$

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough about my question. I would like to understand better the $\alpha$ dependence of the upper bound.  The $(\alpha + 1)^{-1}$ factor (and the $\alpha$ dependence in general) is important for me.

Comment: By the way, I don't think the reduction through rotation to $z$ and $z_0$ having the same real part is correct.